# Possible to layout bokeh y-ticks inside plot

Tags: python, layout, bokeh

I've got a bunch of [bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) hbar plots in which the y-axis ticks are very long:

[image: long y-tick labels]

Some are even worse than this. Can I layout them *inside* the plot, or is there any other way in which to handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure about axis labels, but you can just disable them and add regular text within the bars themselves.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov sounds like a great solution, answer with some sample code and I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment to the question:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[1, 2, 3],
                           y=['a', 'b', 'c']))
p = figure(y_range=sorted(set(ds.data['y'])))
p.hbar(y='y', height=0.8, left=0, right='x', source=ds)
p.text(y='y', text='y', text_baseline='middle', x=0, x_offset=10, color='white', source=ds)
show(p)
```